# Column index of last occurrence of value in each row

Tags: r, indexing, apply

I need to determine the column index for the first and final occurrence of a specific value in each row of a matrix.  For example, if my matrix is the following:

```
 0  10  10  10   0   0
10  10  10   0   0   0
 0   0   0   0  10  10
```

and I need a vector containing the column indices of the first occurrence of 10 in each row and a vector of the final occurrence, the resulting vectors would be `(2,1,5)` and `(4,3,6)`, respectively.

I wrote the following function used it with the apply function to find the first occurrence:

```
Myfunc   <- function(x){which==10)[1]
Myfirst  <- apply(x,1,Myfunc)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get a vector for the final occurrence.  Can someone show me how to use the `which()` function to do this or suggest an alternative method?

Answer (score 4):

```
v1 = apply(df,1,function(x){head(which(x==10),1)}) #First 
v2 = apply(df,1,function(x){tail(which(x==10),1)}) #Last
```

A worked out example:

```
df = rbind(c(0,10,10,10,0,0),c(10,10,10,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,10,10))

> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0   10   10   10    0    0
[2,]   10   10   10    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0   10   10

v1 = apply(df,1,function(x){head(which(x==10),1)}) #First 
> v1
[1] 2 1 5
> is.vector(v1)
[1] TRUE

v2 = apply(df,1,function(x){tail(which(x==10),1)})
> v2
[1] 4 3 6
> is.vector(v2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: rmk, thanks for the response.  I tried your suggestion, but it returned a list instead of a vector and I can't find a way to convert it back to a vector.  Perhaps, I am missing something.

Comment: If your data.frame is has row/col names, `v1` and `v2` should come with names attached, but they should still be vectors as far as I know. Try `dput(df)` or `head(df)` to post some data for more clarifications.

Comment: Brilliant solution, works like a charm for both for first and last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

@rmk's answer will work (+1).  You might also be interested in the [doBy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/index.html) package. It contains a `firstobs()` and a `lastobs()` function that will do what you want.  You could, for example, substitute them in for @rmk's handwritten functions.